# TensorFlow broken data stream reading image file

Tags: python

I have installed tensorflow 0.8.0 in anaconda env called "tensorenv". I then began running basic codes in it in a file called basic_python.py.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# First, load the image
filename = "MarshOrchid.jpg"

image = mpimg.imread(filename)

# Print out its shape
print(image.shape)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(image)

plt.show()
```

This code runs perfectly well. But when i just add to this code the following line

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

to the beginning of the code above the following trace is printed:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_python.py", line 6, in <module>
    image = mpimg.imread(filename)
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1304, in imread
    im = pilread(fname)
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1283, in pilread
    return pil_to_array(image)
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1400, in pil_to_array
    x = toarray(im)
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1383, in toarray
    x_str = im.tobytes('raw', im.mode)
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 678, in tobytes
    self.load()
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 235, in load
    raise_ioerror(e)
  File "/home/shubham/anaconda3/envs/tensorenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 59, in raise_ioerror
    raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")
OSError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

What should I do because in another simple program for addition which I wrote, there this tensorflow import did not cause any problem. But here it causes a lot of problem.

Comment: Can you re-download the image and try again?

Comment: I just did that and same thing happened again. When I dont use that tensorflow import statement the program works pretty well!!!!

Comment: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1057#issuecomment-68203875 suggests you to install `libjpeg8-dev`, so maybe can try `sudo apt install libjpeg8-dev` and reinstall `pillow`?

Comment: I already have that Installed

Answer (score 0):

Try to import PIL before tensorflow. In your case, just put "import tensorflow as tf" after all other imports.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1510). Upgrade Pillow using `pip install Pillow --upgrade` should fix it.

Comment: Sounds like a comment!